# CSS vertical white line issue Chrome and Opera

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-table, opera

I have an issue about vertical white line on Chrome, also on Opera. Microsoft Edge doesn't have this problem.

[Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bcc3aj9t/)

```
<div id="mainContainer" style="margin:auto; text-align: center">

    <table cellspacing="0"; cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="left">Lolo1</td>
                <td class="right" style="background-color: green">BlaBla1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="left">Lolo2</td>
                <td class="right" style="background-color: green">Blabla2</td>
            </tr>              
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

As you see there is an unexpected line on the right, I tried to manipulate it with many ways but no luck yet. It feels like its about the font-size difference between browsers, but it shouldn't be.

Also if you try to remove body elements margin-top, you will see a horizonal white line occurs on the bottom too, thats another strange detail.

Comment: i think it is a resolution problem, you can see it disappears at some zoom levels if you view the fiddle on different zooms. what you are saying doesnt show up on my screen until i changed the zooms.

Comment: Yep you re right. Question is why, its just a basic table with two columns. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

It seems table element's display: inline value causes this problem. Removing it or changing it as display: inline-table made tds perfectly fit into my table.